# Updating the time when a value of a cell in a row changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to update the the time when a value of a cell in a particular row changes. I could do this for one cell at a time, but I'm not able to a do it for a range of cells. 
For example:

```
Name   City   State    Trigger
XYZ    hyd     AP     12:56:51 AM
FGT    mum     MP     12:56:34 AM
```

When I change either of the values in a row, I want the time to be updated in the respective trigger column.

The VBA code I could figure out for updating the time when a change is made in one cell is:

```
Private OldVal As Variant

Public Function AlertOnChange(val)

    If val <> OldVal Then MsgBox "value changed!"

    OldVal = val
    AlertOnChange = Now()

End Function
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the change made manually, or is the change from a formula recalculating?

Comment: "When I change" .. It seems you are changing values manually. You can use [Worksheet_Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.. In case of calculation [Worksheet_Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even))

Comment: Yeah I am manually changing the values;
There is a problem with Worksheet_Change event that, even if I just go to edit mode in a cell without actually changing the value, the time gets updated

Answer (score 0):

You may try to paste the following code into the respective sheet and try. You can format the value according to the format you want

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
 If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 3 Then
  letter = Target.Address
  letter = Replace(letter, "A", "D")
  letter = Replace(letter, "B", "D")
  letter = Replace(letter, "C", "D")
  Range(letter).Value = Now()
 End If
End Sub
```

I am assuming that the columns `Name   City   State    Trigger` are in column `A, B, C and D` accordingly. If it is not, you can change based on your worksheet. Or you even can make it dynamic based on the column alphabets. That needs a few more code though

**Edit 1**

Please add the following code in your sheet VBA. It will do the trick

```
Public oval
Public addressOfOldVal As String
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If oval<> Range(addressOfOldVal).Value Then
 If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 3 Then
  letter = Target.Address
  letter = Replace(letter, "A", "D")
  letter = Replace(letter, "B", "D")
  letter = Replace(letter, "C", "D")
  Range(letter).Value = Now()
 End If
End If
End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
oval = Target.Value
addressOfOldVal = Target.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with the Worksheet_Change event is that, even when I just go to edit mode without actually changing the value, the time gets updated

Comment: @Batman Please see my updated answer and let me know if that solves your issue